# Моя первая программа, просьба указать явные ошибки и как можно укоротить код

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

```py
import re

print ("Проверка имени и возраста(18+) \n")

#Проверка имени
name = None
while name is None:
    name = input (str("Введите имя :\n")).capitalize()
    if not re.findall('[\d]', name) and name.isalpha() and len(name) <=11 :
        print ('Проверка имени успешно завершена') 
    else:
        name = None
        print ("Ошибка! Нельзя использовать цифры или спец символы, ограничение длины не больше 10 символов")
        continue

#Проверка возраста
age = None
while age is None :
    ager = input("Введите возраст :\n")
    try:
        age = int(ager)
    except ValueError:
        print("Ошибка! Используйте пожалуйста цифры")
        continue
    if age > 99 or age < 18:
        print ("Ошибка! Вам нет 18 лет или вам больше 99 лет")
        age = None
        continue
    if len(ager) >=3:
        print ("Ошибка! Вам нет 18 лет или вам больше 99 лет")
        age = None
        continue
    else:
        print ('Проверка возраста успешно завершена') 


print (f"Вас зовут {name}, и вам {ager}")

input("Для завершения программы нажмите ENTER")
```

Comment: Проверка `len(ager) >=3` не нужна. Все остальное в принципе нормально. Ну еще не понятно зачем ограничение на длину имени. Также в имени достаточно проверки `name.isalpha()`, регулярное выражение не нужно.

Comment: имхо: мне почему напоминает это готовый код  из учебников или онлайн-обучалок.

Comment: Insider Повторюсь, код не списан нигде, личная ПЕРВАЯ наработка, можно ли как то укоротить код ?

Comment: insilor Ограничение на кол-во символов сделал что б пользователь не смог написать имени на пол страницы, а на счёт этой проверки: len(ager) >=3 в самой программе можно писать очень большие цифры, я и сам раньше смотрел, тестил, вроде всё должно было работать, но без этого никак, что странно...

Comment: insilor Действительно, проверка len(ager) >=3 не нужна если сделать if int(age) > 99 or int(age) < 18:  Благодарю.

Comment: Мдам, и регулярные выражение так же не нежно, просто раньше где то тестил, и каким то чудом прошли цифры в имени, пришлось дописать... Наверное ошибся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно убрать лишнюю переменную `ager` и делать проверку на число `age = int(input("Введите возраст :\n"))`

Код всей программы:

```
print ("Проверка имени и возраста(18+)\n")

#Проверка имени
name = None
while name is None:
    name = input("Введите имя :\n").capitalize()
    if name.isalpha() and len(name) <=10 :
        print ('Проверка имени успешно завершена') 
    else:
        name = None
        print ("Ошибка! Нельзя использовать цифры или спец символы, ограничение длины не больше 10 символов")
        continue

#Проверка возраста
age = None
while age is None :
    try:
        age = int(input("Введите возраст :\n"))
    except ValueError:
        age = None
        print("Ошибка! Используйте пожалуйста цифры")
        continue
    if age > 99 or age < 18:
        print ("Ошибка! Вам нет 18 лет или вам больше 99 лет")
        age = None
        continue
    else:
        print ('Проверка возраста успешно завершена') 


print (f"Вас зовут {name}, и вам {age}")
input("Для завершения программы нажмите ENTER")
```